# how to find alphabetic equality of two strings - Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I want to find the alphabetic equality(if non-alphabetic characters removed, two strings should be identical) of two strings in javascript.

eg :

```js
const a = "d26$og3" // without non-alphabetic -> dog
const b = "d09*o0376%g@" // without non-alphabetic -> dog

alphabeticallyEqual(a,b) // returns true becuase 'dog' is the contained alphabetic string

const c = "d26$og3" // without non-alphabetic -> dog
const d = "d09*oo0376%g@" // without non-alphabetic -> doog
alphabeticallyEqual(c,d) // returns false dog!=doog
```

I thought of replacing non-alphabetic characters in both strings and then comparing them, but It will consume more time since I have to compare **10000 strings of average length 50**.

How to implement `alphabeticallyEqual` with higher efficiency?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem

Comment: If you use appropriate regex I can not imagine runtime is an issue. I made a jsfiddle and it runs under half a second https://jsfiddle.net/bn8eqj2v/

Comment: What is `alphabeticallyEqual`? Need more info

Comment: The only way to determine what a string will be without non-alphabetic characters is to examine every character. There is no way around that.

Answer (score 1):

First I think you can replace all non-alphabetic chars. You can do that like this

`string.replace(/\W|[0-9]/g,"");`

And then try if they both are identical.

Answer (score -1):

Hello I suggest you use  the method localeCompare().
for example a.localCompare(b);